# Is a base-stock policy optimal for a serial inventory system with upstream stockout costs?

Tags: inventory, multi-echelon, base-stock

In a serial inventory system without fixed costs, an echelon base-stock policy is known to be optimal *if there is no stockout cost at any stage except the last stage*. (This was proved for finite-horizon problems by [Clark and Scarf (1960)](https://pubsonline.informs.org/doi/abs/10.1287/mnsc.6.4.475)<sup>1</sup> and for infinite-horizon problems by [Federgruen and Zipkin (1984)](https://pubsonline.informs.org/doi/abs/10.1287/opre.32.4.818)<sup>2</sup>.)

*What is known about the case in which there are non-zero stockout costs at upstream stages?* Is an echelon base-stock policy known to be optimal or non-optimal?

Whether or not a base-stock policy is optimal, if we assume such a policy is used, are there algorithms for optimizing the base-stock levels, analogous to those by Clark and Scarf (1960) or [Chen and Zheng (1994)](https://pubsonline.informs.org/doi/abs/10.1287/mnsc.40.11.1426)<sup>3</sup>?

---

<sub>References</sub>

<sub>[1] Clark, A. J., Scarf, H. (1960). Optimal Policies for a Multi-Echelon Inventory Problem. *Management Science.* 6(4):475-490.</sub>

<sub>[2] Federgruen, A., Zipkin, P. (1984). Computational Issues in an Infinite-Horizon, Multiechelon Inventory Model. *Operations Research.* 32(4):818-836.</sub>

<sub>[3] Chen, F., Zheng, Y-S. (1994). Lower Bounds for Multi-Echelon Stochastic Inventory Systems. *Management Science.* 40(11):1426-1443.</sub>

Comment: have you checked the reference 'stochastic inventory control' of Evan Porteus?

Comment: @Steven31415 Not recently, but as I recall, that book doesn't cover much (or anything) about multi-echelon inventory optimization -- only single-stage models.